# Binding Click event to dynamically generated div

Tags: jquery, html, events, bind

So im trying to create a dynamic image gallery. And each image created would have a div on top for users to click on.  Im unable to bind a click event to the div

The Code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if()
    {

    }
    else
    {
        var divImgContainer =  '<div id="imgContainer">';
        var divInfo         = '<div id="info">';
        var divDetails      = '<div id="details">';
        var divImage        = '<div id="image">';
        var divVote         = '<div id ="click">';
        for(i=0; i<$ImageArray.length; i++)
        {
             document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += divImgContainer+divInfo+divDetails+'Caption</div>'+divVote+'</div></div>'+divImage+'<a href="img/'+$ImageArray[i].link +'"><img src="'+$ImageArray[i].thumb+'" /></a></div></div>';
         }
        $('#click').click(function()
        {
            alert("click");
        });
    }
});
```

Googling gave two popular answers one is `$('#click').click(function()`  and the other is `$('#click').live(click,function()`  both of which does not work.

Is there any specific way to bind click events for dynamically generated div?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you messing around with `innerHTML`?  Why not just use jQuery to create the elements in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, do not create multiple divs with the same IDs

assuming element id 'click' has class 'vote' and that you want to click on any div with the class 'vote', try this:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.vote', function(e){
    alert("click");
});
```

Comment: Thnx that worked.   Also any other alternative to creating multiple div with same ID, when creating image gallery?

Comment: you can create a variable count and increase it on every loop, then on each line do something like this:
var divDetails      = '<div class="details" id="details-'+count+'">';

Comment: Yes i was planning to do tat. Since i have to create click event for each div, number of event i have to write also increases.

Comment: @de-bugged It shouldn't, the code in this answer will handle click events for all the `div.vote` in `#container`.

Answer (score 0):

To start, the `.live()` method was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in jQuery 1.9, you shouldn't be using that.

You're creating the elements with JavaScript, but you're doing it at page load time, and before you (attempt to) bind the event handler, so that shouldn't be an issue.

However, the problem might be that you're doing this:

```
... + divVote+'</div>...
```

That opens the `<div id="click">` element, then immediately ends it, so it doesn't appear to have any content. If it has no content then it's going to be difficult for you to actually click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
$('#click').click(function(){
     alert("click");
});
```

outside of the

```
$(document).ready(function(){   });
```

and if it doesn't work, then try with

```
$('#click').live(click,function()
```

it might help you

Comment: `$('#click').click(function()` Outside document.ready function also has no result and using `'live' throws error